# Countdown finished

Tags: javascript, html

I have a serious problem to resolve a countdown timer in php.
I use the Keith-Wood countdown plugin and it works very well but I would like to do the following:

When the countdown timer end, I would like update to my data database.

```
 <input class='data<?php echo $id ?>' type='hidden'  value=<?php echo $data; ?> /><br/>
 <span style='font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; margin-left:38px;'>Este Voucher termina</span><br/><br/>
 <div id='defaultCountdown' class='endtime<?php echo $id ?>'></div>
```

My code to start the countdown timer is

```
$(function () {
var i = <?php echo $id ?>;
var dataVal = $('.data' + i.toString()).val();
var data = new Date(dataVal);
str = '.endtime'+i.toString();
$(str).countdown({until: data, format: 'dHMS'});

});
```

My problem is how to check when the timer over.

Comment: read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin provides an 'onExpiry' callback. Example:

```
$(str).countdown({
  until: data,
  format: 'dHMS',
  onExpiry: function() {
    console.log("timer done!");
  }
});
```

Comment: yes, it's described in [documentation](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#onExpiry)